Problem Saving Processed Video and CSV with MoviePy in Python
I'm encountering an issue where the length of the processed video created using MoviePy is shorter than the corresponding CSV file generated by my Mediapipe-based video processing script. Specifically, the video sometimes ends up being 30 seconds long, while the CSV file records events for up to 45 seconds. The CSV file correctly logs timestamps and states, which I have verified. Additionally, the summary lines at the end of the CSV file are not appearing as expected.
Here is the relevant portion of my code:
import csv
from tkinter import messagebox
from moviepy.editor import ImageSequenceClip

# ... [rest of the code]

def process_video(self, camera, perclos_thresh, roll_thresh, pitch_thresh, yaw_thresh,
                  ear_time_thresh, mar_time_thresh, gaze_time_thresh, pose_time_thresh,
                  csv_filename, video_filename):
    # ... [processing code]
    frames_to_video = []  # List to store frames for the video

    # Initializing CSV
    with open(csv_filename, mode='w', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow(['Timestamp', 'Cansado', 'Dormindo', 'Olhando Fora', 'Distraído', 'Bocejando'])

        # ... [rest of the processing loop]
        
        # Finalizing CSV
        with open(csv_filename, mode='a', newline='') as file_append:
            writer_append = csv.writer(file_append)
            # Calculate final durations for active states
            # ... [write summary lines]

    # Create the video from the list of frames using moviepy
    try:
        video_clip = ImageSequenceClip(frames_to_video, fps=real_fps)
        video_clip.write_videofile(video_filename, codec='libx264')
    except Exception as e:
        messagebox.showerror("Erro ao salvar o vídeo", f"Ocorreu um erro ao salvar o vídeo: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = VideoProcessingApp()
    app.mainloop()


Issue:
The video duration is sometimes shorter than the CSV file duration.
The final summary lines are not appearing in the CSV file.
What I've Tried:
I've ensured that the CSV file correctly logs timestamps and states.
Question: Can anyone help identify why the video duration might be shorter than the CSV file and why the summary lines are missing from the CSV file? Are there potential issues in how the frames are collected and saved, or in how the CSV file is being finalized?

[mre] required. that includes data. a MRE is not a complete dump of your project. a MRE produces the issue and nothing else.

You can add a print statement to check how many frames are being added to frames_to_video and ensure that the number matches the timestamps in the CSV file. It would also help to print the time when the last frame is collected and compare it with the timestamps in the CSV to see if they align. Additionally, include print statements or error handling around the part of your code that writes the summary lines to the CSV file. This will help confirm if that section is running as expected.
